# Finding Probability of Multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, multinomial, probability-distribution

A bag contain 5 dices and each have six faces with probability $p_1$=$p_2$=$p_3$=$2*p_4$=$2*p_5$=$3*p_6$. What is the probability of selecting two dice with face 4, and three dice with face 1?
Someone have try the codes for this problem in r shown in picture but I not understand how the probability is obtained. Kindly explain me the answer for this problem.

[image]

Comment: What programming language is that? Please never post screenshots of code - post the code.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find `p_i`s values based on the given equalities and the following assumption (replace all `p_i`s based on their relations with `p_6` to find it, then find the value of each `p_i`):

```
p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 + p_6 = 1
```

To find the probability, we need to select `2` out of `5` of dices with face `4` which its probability is `p_4^2` and for other dices, they should have face `1` that it's probability is `p_1^3`.

Now, to understand the last step, you should read the explanation of the `dmultinom(x, size, prob)` function (from [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Multinom.html)):

> Generate multinomially distributed random number vectors and compute multinomial probabilities. If `x` is a K-component vector, `dmultinom(x, prob)` is the probability
> `P(X[1]=x[1], … , X[K]=x[k]) = C * prod(j=1 , …, K) p[j]^x[j]`. where `C` is the ‘multinomial coefficient’ `C = N! / (x[1]! * … * x[K]!)` and `N = sum(j=1, …, K) x[j]`.
> By definition, each component `X[j]` is binomially distributed as `Bin(size, prob[j])` for `j = 1, …, K`.

Therefore, `dmultinom(j, n, p)` means `C(5,2) * p_1^3 * p_4^2`, as `j = (3, 0, 0, 2, 0)`, `n=5`, and `p = (p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6)`.